# Can't read .animVal during SVG SMIL animation

Tags: javascript, svg, smil

***This is for the SVG animation experts:***

I'm trying to read the properties of a `<g>` element that I'm animating along a path using `<animateMotion>`. My understanding is that `animateMotion` applies a `transform` to the element, instead of simply changing one property at a time (x, y, rotation, etc).

According to my notes, you can access the current animated value of any SVG attribute in Javascript with the `animVal` sub-property of the relevant property. For example, `element.cx.animVal.value` or `element.cx.animVal.valueAsString`.

*But for transforms*, the corresponding property is `element.transform`, which is of type [SVGAnimatedTransformList](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGAnimatedTransformList). The `animVal` of the transform returns an [SVGTransformList](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGTransformList). Reading through the spec at that link, I should be able to get these properties from my animated element:

`element.transform.animVal.numberOfItems`
should return the number of items in the transform list. But instead, it returns `0`.

`element.transform.animVal.getItem(0)` should return the first value in the transform list. Since it's apparently empty, I get an error when trying to access this property.

**So, has anyone successfully used these properties and sub-properties to read values during animation, are they known to be problematic or unsupported, or am I doing something wrong?**

Other things to note about my script:

- tested in Firefox and Chrome
- i'm logging out the properties every second with a `setInterval`
- the animation itself works fine. how I got there shouldn't matter too much but I can answer your questions with more details

Comment: animateMotion applies a supplemental transform, it does not modify the existing transform.

Comment: animateTransform animates the existing transform, you could read the changes that makes using animVal.

Comment: hmm, okay, how do I read the properties of this supplemental transform though? that seems to be my problem.

I added a simple transform to my `<g>` element just to see if that gets updated. `element.transform.animVal.numberOfItems` returns `1`, which seems to be true... but digging through the console log I see that it contains the transform matrix of the initial transform.

the SVGAnimatedTransformList is supposed to contain `.baseVal` and `.animVal`, where baseVal returns the inital value of the transform before animation, and animVal returns the updated value during animation.

Comment: Yup, I just cannot read the values of the translation being applied to the animated element. When I go by the spec, all I get returned is the information about the _explicit_ transform property applied to the element, if present. SMIL is proving pretty useless for me - most browsers don't fire the `beginEvent`, `endEvent` or `repeatEvent` animation events, and now trying to keep track of the animated properties in lieu of those events is proving to be difficult.

Comment: Firefox fires all those animation events.